# Build error in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm new to both Eclipse and Java.

I'm wondering if the following is an error in Eclipses compiler or my installation.

I have defined a public class inside a public class to define a return type for a service method.

```
public class ServiceThing {
    public class ReturnType {...}
    public ReturnType serviceMethod (...) {...}
    ...
}
```

In the class where I call the service method I instatiate a ReturnType to hold a default message:

```
ReturnType returnType = new ReturnType(...);
```

When a try to build this I get the following errors:

Building workspace:
Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Java Builder' on project 'XXXX.android'.
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Save failed:
Save Failed;
java.lang.NullPointerException

I found out that the required syntax is:

```
ServiceThing serviceThing = ...; 
ReturnType returnType = serviceThing.new ReturnType(...);
```

But the compiler should not generate a nullpointerException anyway.

Comment: May I ask why do you need a public class inside a public class? If its public, why not make it a stand-alone class altogether.

Comment: It's just to give a strong indication of the intention of the class. It's purely ment to be used for a return type of the service call.
If I put it into sparate file I think it would look messy since it doesn't have a life on its own

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By making `ReturnType` a `public static class` you will get rid of the reference to the parent instance and your

```
ReturnType returnType = new ReturnType(...);
```

will work as you expected it to.

Without the `static` modifier instances of subclasses contain an implicit reference to their parent objects. That is the reason why you need a `ServiceThing` instance to create an instance of `ReturnType` in this case.

Comment: Nice answer. This solution is actually endorsed in [Effective Java, Second Edition](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/effective/) in Item 22: Favor static member classes over nonstatic.

I still think the compiler should have written this error message: It is impossible to create an instance of a nonstatic member class without an enclosing instance.